# Upload to Heroku from GitHub other ways

Tags: github, heroku

As the GitHub linking is no longer working due to security issues, my app is still on GitHub and I want to put it on Heroku how do I do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the security notification says](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413), you can still [deploy via `git push`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-git).

Assuming you have a local copy of your repository¹ and you would normally do something like `git push origin main` to deploy to GitHub:

1. `cd` to your project directory
2. Check your remotes:

   ```
   git remote -v
   ```
3. Do you see a Heroku remote?

   - If so, make note of its name and go to the next step.
   - Otherwise, [add one](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-git-remote):

     ```
     heroku git:remote -a YOUR_APP_NAME
     ```
4. Now, push directly to the Heroku remote. Assuming it is called `heroku`:

   ```
   git push heroku main
   ```
5. You'll probably also want to push to GitHub to ensure the code for your latest release is synced.

I believe this is the simplest option if you're migrating from GitHub integration, but the documentation also [lists other options](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/integrating-with-version-control-providers-besides-github):

- [Docker-based deployments](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime)
- Using [`dpl`](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl)
- Via Git hook
- [Via Terraform](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-terraform-with-heroku)

---

¹If, for whatever reason, you *don't* have a local copy of your repository, `git clone` it from GitHub and then proceed as above.